# Expanding Data Table created

Tags: python, sql

I am a Python beginner. I found this code that works perfectly for me (connecting IP21 to Power BI) - just trying to increase the number of tags (information)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('NAME')
tag = 'MYTAG'
start = '2019-01-01 12:00:00'
end = '2019-10-02 12:00:00'
sql = "select TS,VALUE from HISTORY "\
        "where NAME='%s'"\
        "and PERIOD = 60*10"\
        "and REQUEST = 2"\
        "and REQUEST=2 and TS between TIMESTAMP'%s' and TIMESTAMP'%s'" % (tag, start, end)
data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn) # Pandas DataFrame with your data!
```

Instead of this, I just want tag1, tag2, ... and get data which is a table with date and all those values. How do I change the code? I got an answer that makes the code run, but I think my sequel programming gets messed up. Instead of name being one tag, it makes the search name **(tag1,tag2)** which is not a valid search name. How do you find multiple things in sequel?
I want to change this as

```
tag = ' TAG1'
tag2 =' TAG2'
start = '2019-01-01 12:00:00'
end = '2019-10-02 12:00:00'
sql = "select TS,VALUE from HISTORY "\
        "where NAME=('%s,%s)'"\
        "and PERIOD = 60*10"\
        "and REQUEST = 2"\
        "and REQUEST=2 and TS between TIMESTAMP'%s' and TIMESTAMP'%s'" % (tag, tag2, start, end)
data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn) # Pandas DataFrame with your data!
```

something like that.
This works but is giving an empty table. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using tag1, tag2, etc. instead of `'MYTAG'`? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Did you look at the definition of the [tag:sequel] tag? [tag:sequel] is a Ruby-specific ORM.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:sequel] tag is a Ruby ORM.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well. You want to have information for some tags. So just adapt the condition for the tag in the query. What you should notice is that there is a %s for each tags. So if you want to add a tag add a %s in the query and add the corresponding variable after % in the brackets. Try to learn who to do sting replacement in python. It is easy.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('NAME')
tag = 'MYTAG'
start = '2019-01-01 12:00:00'
end = '2019-10-02 12:00:00'
sql = "select TS,VALUE from HISTORY "\
        "WHERE NAME in ('%s', '%s')"\
        "and PERIOD = 60*10"\
        "and REQUEST = 2"\
        "and REQUEST=2 and TS between TIMESTAMP'%s' and TIMESTAMP'%s'" % (tag, start, end)
data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn) # Pandas DataFrame with your data!
```

Comment: Thank you - I still want to list a few tags. All won't work.  - I have tried to explain better.

Comment: Thank you! The code worked, but still need help :-) Not sure if you can help with sequel programming too.